# Abstracting over groups of assertions in Z3/SMT-LIB

Tags: z3, smt

Are there good mechanisms in Z3 to abstract over assertions? I want to create a “function” that takes in parameters and makes assertions about those parameters, possibly with “local variable” definitions in it.

Imagine that I have a `String` and I want to assert that it represents a decimal number between 13 and 24. I could write a combination of regular expression assertions about the string and combine it with a `str.to.int` range assertion. I can do that directly, but if I have dozens of such variables I want to make the assertion about, it gets repetitive. I can use an external language API, or perhaps define a macro/function returning a boolean inside Z3 and assert that it’s true, but that feels a bit indirect. What’s idiomatic here? I want it to be just as easy for Z3 to solve as writing the assertions out by hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `define-fun` to define a Boolean function `f` such that you can `(assert (f x y z ...))`, where `f` can of course be a conjunction of multiple conditions. The `define-fun` will be inlined by Z3's SMT2 frontend, i.e., there should not be any runtime cost to it.

(Z3 also supports macros defined via `(forall ((x ...)) (= (f x ...) ...))`, but you need to explicitly apply the model-finder tactic to inline them.)